# Form not working in Chrome when using CSS transform - rotate

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform

I am currently building a page which contains a box which when hovered on, another div that is absolutely positioned behind it and hidden rotates into view. This div contains a form.

This is working fine on Firefox and IE, but when I attempt to use in Chrome, the form becomes unresponsive, almost as if the select boxes are not working.

Here is a rough JSFiddle I have created. Hover on the red box and try and use the form that pops up and you should hopefully see the problem (Please make sure you open the JSFiddle using Google Chrome).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TR23z/)

I have never encountered this problem before so am not sure where to start really so an advice would be great.

Thanks

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');" class="item small lamp-finder-wrapper flip-container col6" style="">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front-side" id="side-1">
            <a href="/~gvmulti/index.php/technologies/2?search=&amp;order=i.ordering&amp;dir=asc&amp;cm=0#tlb" style="display: block; background-image: url('/~gvmulti/images/lampFinder.jpg')" class="image"></a>          
        </div>
        <div class="back-side" id="side-2">
            <h3>Lamp Finder</h3>
            <div class="overlay">
                <img src="/~gvmulti/images/loading-text.gif">   
            </div>

                                            <form id="lamp-finder">         
                <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer: </label>
                <select name="manufacturer">
                    <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
                                                <option value="_empty_"></option>
                                                <option value="177">3M</option>
                                                <option value="018">Acer</option>
                                                <option value="109">BENQ</option>
                                                <option value="191">Barco</option>
                                                <option value="087">Canon</option>
                                                <option value="014">Casio</option>
                                                <option value="217">Dell</option>
                                                <option value="232">Eiki</option>
                                                <option value="119">Elmo</option>
                                                <option value="027">Epson</option>
                                                <option value="032">Hitachi</option>
                                                <option value="172">JVC</option>
                                                <option value="088">Mitsubishi</option>
                                                <option value="131">NEC</option>
                                                <option value="196">Optoma</option>
                                                <option value="058">Panasonic</option>
                                                <option value="171">Philips</option>
                                                <option value="234">Plus</option>
                                                <option value="252">Projection Design</option>
                                                <option value="374">SMART</option>
                                                <option value="013">Sanyo</option>
                                                <option value="065">Sharp</option>
                                                <option value="096">Sony</option>
                                                <option value="233">Taxan</option>
                                                <option value="201">Themescene</option>
                                                <option value="108">Toshiba</option>
                                                <option value="235">Vivitek</option>
                                        </select>
                <label for="projector">Projector: </label>
                <select name="projector" disabled="">
                    <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <div class="lamp-results">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    /* Lamp Finder */
.lamp-finder-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 300px;
}

#lamp-finder label {
    color: #E86017;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#lamp-finder select {
    padding: 7px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.lamp-finder-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.lamp-finder-wrapper h3 {
    background-color: red;
    text-indent: 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.lamp-finder-wrapper .overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../../../images/trans.png);
}

.lamp-finder-wrapper .image {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.lamp-finder-wrapper .overlay img {
    width: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    position: absolute;
}

.lamp-results ul {
    margin-left: 14px;
}

.lamp-results ul li {
    color: #E86017;
}

.lamp-results ul li,.lamp-results ul li span {
    float: left;
}

.lamp-results ul li span {
    clear: both;
    color: #fff;
}

#side-2 {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background: #333;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    width: 193px;
    height: 396px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#side-2 form {
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
}

#side-1 {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 193px;
    height: 396px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper .back-side {
    z-index: 3000;
}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transition: .6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.back-side {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: I dont know why is this but when `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` is removed select works. in `.flip-container:hover .flipper`

Comment: Hi,Yes I just noticed that too. It stop working in Internet Exporer which is strange though. Thanks